# Exporting all product fields in Prestashop 1.6?

Tags: csv, prestashop, export-to-csv, prestashop-1.6

I am using Prestashop 1.6.0.9 and when I have uploaded a CSV file with all the possible fields completed. Then I edited few products in the BackOffice and saved it all. Now, when I click on the export icon, it prompts me to open/save a csv file. However, when I open it - only the ID, Image, Name, Reference, Category, Base Price, Final Price, Quantity and Status fields are exported. I would like to be able to export a similar file to what I imported in. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is not the prettiest way (I don't PS very well, it's structure, overrides etc.) but look simply into: controllers\admin\AdminProductsController.php.

Near line 150 add new field definition like:

```
$this->fields_list['custom_field'] = array(
            'title' => "Name from lang",
            'havingFilter' => false,
            'orderby' => false,
            'search' => false
        );
```

Hope it's not too late to answering this. :)

Comment: Mind explaning what it does?

Comment: When PS is going to collect product data for export it's iterating $this->fields_list array (by foreach) and tries to assign all this array keys you specified ('custom_field') with fields data from ps_product table.

Comment: So I have to copy+paste this code for each field I want to export?

Comment: Yes. Look into AdminProductsController.php and notice that this is already done for certain fields. Bear in mind that adding this fields will make it also villible in admin panel in Products tab if you don't add some conditional rule for your custom fields.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Look into AdminProductsController.php and notice that this is already done for certain fields. Bear in mind that adding this fields will make it **also villible in admin panel in Products tab if you don't add some conditional rule for your custom fields** What did you mean by that webrama.pl ??

Answer (score 0):

Prestashop By default does not export any more information except than which are display in Product list.

that list are called **fields_list** in prestashop.

Check `controllers/admin/AdminProductsController.php file`

Around line 200, you will find how **fields_list** are generated

with starting of 
**$this->fields_list = array();**

Above that code, you will find some sql queries which will get necessary products data by joining with various tables.

you can add other parameters in select query.

i add wholesale_price in select query to export wholesale_price for all products.

```
$this->_select .= 'shop.`name` AS `shopname`, a.`wholesale_price`, a.`id_shop_default`, ';
```

Now this fields_list will display in product listing and will also display in CSV export.

No need to write extra code to add **fields_list** in export CSV file.